# Spring not Logging jog4J XML

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Issue: I'm trying to get a log of all the Spring JDBC transactions but no logging except my own logs are being written.

`Log4j.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="ALL">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/BuildingMaterials.log" 
        filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/BuildingMaterials.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000 KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${sys:catalina.home}/logs" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="BuildingMaterials.log-*"/>
                    <!--<IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="4"/>-->
                    <IfLastModified age="14d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <level value="trace" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils">
            <level value="trace" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </logger>
   <!-- <logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </logger>-->
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I'm using gradle for the dependency management

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.0'
```

Currently all I have tried is in the XML  but nothing is logging i'm not sure if it is a spring issue where I need to tell spring to use jog4j or if it is the XML itself.

the application is running on a linux machine. Since my own logging statements are getting logged I don't believe this is an issue with permissions.

Comment: Without more details, it is difficult to say what's wrong. Can you share your project folder structure and where you are keeping this file? The file should be kept in the class path root e.g. src/main/resources or src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: Could you show us your code? Especially, imported classes and using `Logger `